# D3.js. Grouping data in bar chart using d3.nest()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

*I am just learning d3.js and my javascript level is basic.
Thanks for the help, much appreciated.*

### Total number of clicks pr. Campaign.

I have a csv file with colums: "Campaign" and "Clicked". 
"Clicked" column consist of values: Clicked / No Click.
I want to display total Clicked per Campaign. I don't care about No Click.
I have made a function to count clicked and store the count in each data member. I use d.count to set y domain.
The y axis and x axis are displayed correct.
But the values in the bars does not show. 
I assume these two lines of code are incorrect:

.attr("y", f

```
unction(d) { return y(d.key); })
.attr("height"
, function(d) { return height - y(d.key); });
```

In the console I get this error:

d3.v4.min

> .js:2 Error:  attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".
>   d3.v4.min.j
>
> s:2 Error:  attribute height: Expected length, "NaN"

As I have two values for column Clicked: "Clicked" and "No Click", I assume I have to exclude value "No Click" in my d3.nest() function?

How do I display the values of Clicked per Campaign? What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>barChart</title>
</head>
<style> /* set the CSS */

.bar { fill: steelblue; }

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->   
<script src="d3.v4.js"></script>    
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="d3.min.js"></script>-->

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get the data 
    d3.csv("EmailMarketingCampaign_Data.csv")
    .row(function(d){ return {Campaign: (d.Campaign), Clicked: (d.Clicked)}; })
    .get(function(error,data){
    console.log(data[0]);

 // format all data from strings
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.data = +d.data;   
  });

// Array [ Object, Object ] Key: Clicked, Key: No Clicked
     var nested_data = d3.nest()
     .key(function(d) { return d.Clicked; })
    .rollup(function(values) {
     return values.length; 
     })
     .entries(data);        
     console.log(nested_data);

// count all clicked to set range for y axis

      var countObj = {};

        // count Clicked 
        data.forEach(function(d) {
        var Clicked = d.Clicked;
        if(countObj[Clicked] === undefined) {
        countObj[Clicked] = 0;
        } else {
        countObj[Clicked] = countObj[Clicked] + 1;
        }
        });
        // now store the count in each data member
        data.forEach(function(d) {
        var Clicked = d.Clicked;
        d.count = countObj[Clicked];
        });
        console.log(countObj);


  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Campaign; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")

      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Campaign); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())

      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.key); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.key); });



  // add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### EmailMarketingCampaign_Data.csv

Ca

> mpaign,Click_Date,Start,End,Clicked,clickedFlag,Customer
>   ID,weekDay,Age,Country,Demographic,Gender JAN
>   SALES,30/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,10,Sun,30,UK,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,31/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,11,Mon,26,UK,Adult,Female
>   JAN
>   SALES,01/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,12,Tue,59,UK,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,02/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,13,Wed,3,UK,Child,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,03/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,14,Thu,59,Germany,Adult,Female
>   JAN SALES,04/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No
>   Click,0,15,Fri,39,UK,Adult,Male JAN
>   SALES,05/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,16,Sat,19,UK,Adult,Male
>   JAN SALES,07/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No
>   Click,0,18,Mon,25,UK,Adult,Male JAN
>   SALES,08/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,19,Tue,6,UK,Child,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,09/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,20,Wed,55,Germany,Adult,Female
>   JAN
>   SALES,10/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,21,Thu,19,UK,Adult,Male
>   JAN SALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No
>   Click,0,22,Fri,32,UK,Adult,Male JAN
>   SALES,12/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,23,Sat,18,UK,Adult,Female
>   JAN
>   SALES,14/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,25,Mon,7,UK,Child,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,30/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,32,Sun,59,France,Adult,Female
>   JAN
>   SALES,31/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,33,Mon,28,France,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,01/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,34,Tue,31,UK,Adult,Male
>   JAN SALES,02/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No
>   Click,0,35,Wed,3,France,Child,Female JAN
>   SALES,03/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,36,Thu,38,France,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,04/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,37,Fri,50,France,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,05/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,38,Sat,57,France,Adult,Female
>   JAN
>   SALES,06/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,39,Sun,38,France,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,07/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,40,Mon,31,UK,Adult,Male
>   JAN SALES,08/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No
>   Click,0,41,Tue,33,France,Adult,Female JAN
>   SALES,09/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,42,Wed,34,France,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,10/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,43,Thu,59,France,Adult,Male
>   JAN SALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No
>   Click,0,44,Fri,13,France,Teen,Female JAN
>   SALES,12/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,45,Sat,2,France,Child,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,13/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,46,Sun,39,UK,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,30/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,54,Sun,18,France,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,01/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,55,Tue,13,France,Teen,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,56,Fri,50,France,Adult,Female
>   JAN SALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No
>   Click,0,57,Fri,19,France,Adult,Male JAN
>   SALES,03/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,58,Thu,22,USA,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,04/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,59,Fri,11,USA,Child,Female
>   JAN SALES,05/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No
>   Click,0,60,Sat,56,USA,Adult,Male JAN
>   SALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,61,Fri,7,USA,Child,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,07/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,62,Mon,9,USA,Child,Female
>   JAN
>   SALES,08/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,63,Tue,43,France,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,09/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,64,Wed,2,France,Child,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,66,Fri,32,USA,Adult,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,12/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,67,Sat,4,USA,Child,Male
>   JAN
>   SALES,13/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,68,Sun,47,USA,Adult,Female
>   JAN SALES,14/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No
>   Click,0,69,Mon,49,USA,Adult,Male Unknown,01/02/2013,,,No
>   Click,0,2,Fri,33,France,Adult,Female
>   Unknown,01/03/2013,,,Clicked,1,3,Fri,17,Germany,Teen,Male
>   Unknown,06/03/2013,,,Clicked,1,17,Wed,1,UK,Child,Female
>   Unknown,13/02/2013,,,Clicked,1,24,Wed,5,UK,Child,Male
>   Unknown,14/03/2013,,,Clicked,1,47,Thu,22,France,Adult,Female
>   Unknown,10/04/2013,,,Clicked,1,65,Wed,11,USA,Child,Female
>   XMAS,28/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,1,Fri,24,UK,Adult,Male
>   XMAS,24/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,4,Mon,18,UK,Adult,Male
>   XMAS,25/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,5,Tue,19,UK,Adult,Female
>   XMAS,26/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,No
>   Click,0,6,Wed,58,UK,Adult,Male
>   XMAS,27/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,7,Thu,16,Germany,Teen,Male
>   XMAS,28/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,8,Fri,26,UK,Adult,Female
>   XMAS,29/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,No
>   Click,0,9,Sat,37,UK,Adult,Male
>   XMAS,24/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,26,Mon,19,Germany,Adult,Female
>   XMAS,25/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,27,Tue,43,UK,Adult,Male
>   XMAS,26/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,No
>   Click,0,28,Wed,20,UK,Adult,Male
>   XMAS,27/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,29,Thu,19,France,Adult,Female
>   XMAS,28/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,30,Fri,58,France,Adult,Male
>   XMAS,29/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,No
>   Click,0,31,Sat,7,France,Child,Male
>   XMAS,24/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,No
>   Click,0,48,Mon,3,France,Child,Male
>   XMAS,25/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,49,Tue,25,France,Adult,Male
>   XMAS,26/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,50,Wed,18,France,Adult,Female
>   XMAS,27/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,No
>   Click,0,51,Thu,5,France,Child,Male
>   XMAS,28/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,52,Fri,1,UK,Child,Male
>   XMAS,29/12/2012,23/12/2012,29/12/2012,Clicked,1,53,Sat,0,France,Child,Female

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ohn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two level grouping in your `nested_data` and then use just the "Clicked" group for the scales calculations and the data binding.

```js
var dataString = "Campaign,Click_Date,Start,End,Clicked,clickedFlag,Customer ID,weekDay,Age,Country,Demographic,Gender \nEXTORTION,30/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,10,Sun,30,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,31/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,11,Mon,26,UK,Adult,Female \nSALES,01/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,12,Tue,59,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,02/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,13,Wed,3,UK,Child,Male \nSALES,03/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,14,Thu,59,Germany,Adult,Female \nSALES,04/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,15,Fri,39,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,05/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,16,Sat,19,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,07/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,18,Mon,25,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,08/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,19,Tue,6,UK,Child,Male \nSALES,09/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,20,Wed,55,Germany,Adult,Female \nSALES,10/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,21,Thu,19,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,22,Fri,32,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,12/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,23,Sat,18,UK,Adult,Female \nSALES,14/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,25,Mon,7,UK,Child,Male \nSALES,30/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,32,Sun,59,France,Adult,Female \nSALES,31/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,33,Mon,28,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,01/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,34,Tue,31,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,02/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,35,Wed,3,France,Child,Female \nSALES,03/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,36,Thu,38,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,04/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,37,Fri,50,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,05/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,38,Sat,57,France,Adult,Female \nSALES,06/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,39,Sun,38,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,07/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,40,Mon,31,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,08/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,41,Tue,33,France,Adult,Female \nSALES,09/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,42,Wed,34,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,10/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,43,Thu,59,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,44,Fri,13,France,Teen,Female \nSALES,12/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,45,Sat,2,France,Child,Male \nSALES,13/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,46,Sun,39,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,30/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,54,Sun,18,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,01/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,55,Tue,13,France,Teen,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,56,Fri,50,France,Adult,Female \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,57,Fri,19,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,03/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,58,Thu,22,USA,Adult,Male \nSALES,04/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,59,Fri,11,USA,Child,Female \nSALES,05/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,60,Sat,56,USA,Adult,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,61,Fri,7,USA,Child,Male \nSALES,07/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,62,Mon,9,USA,Child,Female \nSALES,08/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,63,Tue,43,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,09/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,64,Wed,2,France,Child,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,66,Fri,32,USA,Adult,Male \nSALES,12/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,67,Sat,4,USA,Child,Male \nSALES,13/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,68,Sun,47,USA,Adult,Female \nSALES,14/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,69,Mon,49,USA,Adult,Male"
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get the data 
var data = d3.csvParse(dataString);

//console.log(data[0]);

// format all data from strings
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.data = +d.data;
});

// Array [ Object, Object ] Key: Clicked, Key: No Clicked
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Clicked;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Campaign
  })
  .rollup(function(values) {
    return values.length;
  })
  .entries(data);

var clicked_data = nested_data.find(d => d.key == "Clicked").values

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(clicked_data.map(function(d) {
  return d.key;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(clicked_data, function(d) {
  return d.value;
})]);

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(clicked_data)
  .enter().append("rect")

  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.key);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())

  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  });



// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see I had a lot of missing links. 
I have now modified my code according to your suggestions. 
It works. Thank you very much, I would not have been able to solve this myself. 
I am trying to use the same nested_data to display the clicked_data in a line (d3.line generator) with x-axis as "Click_Date" AND y-axis "Clicked" values, 
categorized by the 3 campaigns: Jan, Xmas and Undefined. 
So I am using d3.line() and path. 
I get this error in the console.log: Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,0Z". 
And when I "console.log", I can see that clicked_data is being read like this: [Object]0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)concat: function concat()constructor: function Array()
Here is the code. I assume I have to work on this bit here:

> svg.append("path")
>             .data([clicked_data])
>             .attr("class", "line")
>             .attr("d", valueline);

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.key); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
console.log(valueline);

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("EmailMarketingCampaign_Data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

/*  function convert(d) {
  return {
    date: new Date(d.Click_Date),
    value: +d.value         // convert string to number
  };
} */

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Click_Date = parseTime(d.Click_Date);
      d.value = +d.value;
  });

    /* Two level grouping in nested_data: Clicked and Campaign */

var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Clicked;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Click_Date
  })
  .rollup(function(values) {
    return values.length;
  })
  .entries(data);

/* Get values from key "Clicked" and put in clicked_date */

var clicked_data = nested_data.find(d => d.key == "Clicked").values

console.log(clicked_data);

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(clicked_data, function(d) { return d.key; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(clicked_data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data([clicked_data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

```js
var dataString = "Campaign,Click_Date,Start,End,Clicked,clickedFlag,Customer ID,weekDay,Age,Country,Demographic,Gender \nEXTORTION,30/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,10,Sun,30,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,31/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,11,Mon,26,UK,Adult,Female \nSALES,01/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,12,Tue,59,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,02/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,13,Wed,3,UK,Child,Male \nSALES,03/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,14,Thu,59,Germany,Adult,Female \nSALES,04/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,15,Fri,39,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,05/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,16,Sat,19,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,07/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,18,Mon,25,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,08/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,19,Tue,6,UK,Child,Male \nSALES,09/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,20,Wed,55,Germany,Adult,Female \nSALES,10/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,21,Thu,19,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,22,Fri,32,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,12/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,23,Sat,18,UK,Adult,Female \nSALES,14/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,25,Mon,7,UK,Child,Male \nSALES,30/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,32,Sun,59,France,Adult,Female \nSALES,31/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,33,Mon,28,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,01/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,34,Tue,31,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,02/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,35,Wed,3,France,Child,Female \nSALES,03/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,36,Thu,38,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,04/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,37,Fri,50,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,05/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,38,Sat,57,France,Adult,Female \nSALES,06/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,39,Sun,38,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,07/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,40,Mon,31,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,08/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,41,Tue,33,France,Adult,Female \nSALES,09/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,42,Wed,34,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,10/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,43,Thu,59,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,44,Fri,13,France,Teen,Female \nSALES,12/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,45,Sat,2,France,Child,Male \nSALES,13/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,46,Sun,39,UK,Adult,Male \nSALES,30/12/2012,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,54,Sun,18,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,01/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,55,Tue,13,France,Teen,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,56,Fri,50,France,Adult,Female \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,57,Fri,19,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,03/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,58,Thu,22,USA,Adult,Male \nSALES,04/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,59,Fri,11,USA,Child,Female \nSALES,05/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,60,Sat,56,USA,Adult,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,61,Fri,7,USA,Child,Male \nSALES,07/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,62,Mon,9,USA,Child,Female \nSALES,08/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,63,Tue,43,France,Adult,Male \nSALES,09/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,64,Wed,2,France,Child,Male \nSALES,11/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,66,Fri,32,USA,Adult,Male \nSALES,12/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,67,Sat,4,USA,Child,Male \nSALES,13/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,Clicked,1,68,Sun,47,USA,Adult,Female \nSALES,14/01/2013,30/12/2012,29/01/2013,No Click,0,69,Mon,49,USA,Adult,Male"
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get the data 
var data = d3.csvParse(dataString);

//console.log(data[0]);

// format all data from strings
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.data = +d.data;
});

// Array [ Object, Object ] Key: Clicked, Key: No Clicked
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Clicked;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Campaign
  })
  .rollup(function(values) {
    return values.length;
  })
  .entries(data);

var clicked_data = nested_data.find(d => d.key == "Clicked").values

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(clicked_data.map(function(d) {
  return d.key;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(clicked_data, function(d) {
  return d.value;
})]);

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(clicked_data)
  .enter().append("rect")

  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.key);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())

  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  });



// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```